# Double-spaced Bullet List

Tags: html, list, css, validation, newline

I have a bulleted list which I am trying to double space.  While simply inserting `<br>`s works, it does not pass the validity test.

```
Element br not allowed as child of element ul in this context.
```

Using `line-height: 2em;` works, but it misaligns my bullets.

Using CSS3, how can I double-space a bulleted list while keeping my bullets vertically aligned with my text?

Comment: Add `margin-bottom` to `li`?

Answer (score 0):

Adding the following CSS should solve the issue

**CSS**

```
ul li {
    margin-bottom:1em;
}
```

The value might need tweaking slightly.